What is "final sequence of breakpoints"?
On p.114 in TeXbook it is said:

penalties are discarded after a break in a paragraph only if they do not belong to the
final sequence of breakpoints

What is "final sequence of breakpoints"?
Could somebody give an example when penalties are discarded and when not?
By the way, on p.314 in TeXbook it is said:

if you have two penalties in a row, their
combined effect is the same as a single penalty whose value is the minimum of the two
original values, unless both of those values force breaks

Does the rule in the second quotation follow from the rule in the first one?

I thought 'final' was as opposed to 'possible' since there are lots of possible break points, but most of them don't actually become breaks. why do you think the second follows from the first?

@cfr these quotations should be connected somehow because they are referring to one subject

ok, but that is much weaker than one following from the other ;).

If you had included the first half of the sentence in the first quotation, then it would be saying exactly the same thing as the second. The first discusses \break\break and the second discusses both of those values force breaks  which is the same thing.

There is an example when they are not discarded immediately before the quoted line. (\break\break in horizontal mode does not discard the second penalty).
Almost all other examples of adjacent penalties are combined and treated as one, so are discarded if the line break is taken.
The sentence that ends with the text you quote starts:

But if you say \break\break in a
paragraph, the second \break causes an empty line, because

